java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject - Json jar missing?
(https://i.sstatic.net/y4MCV.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/Ojqe6.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/nfe5E.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/rWNcs.png) - Error message
Have i not included the json-simple jar correctly? I have included images to show my setup.
i have tried adding json-simple with maven and added the jar manually, neither seem to work

Hi, can you share the full/key project via Google Drive or GitHub? From the image, I'm not sure of the reason. And which version of IDEA you are using?
